# Looping thru defines

Tags: c, variables

Say I have a list of defines MC_SERVER1, MC_SERVER2, MC_SERVER3 how would I loop thru to get the contents of each. Also I do not know how many I will have. I might have 3 or 10. This is for C programming

Say I have 
DEFINE MC_SERVER1="mc1.sdsds.com"
DEFINE MC_SERVER2="mc2.sdsds.com"

how do I loop thru them all.

Comment: Short answer: You don't. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Define "content". What are your macros? Constants? Expressions? Please explain in more detail what you intend to accomplish.

Comment: I guess he means something like `for (i=0;i<STATE_LAST;i++){printf("%s\n",mnemo[i]);}`

Comment: I don't think that it be possible. (C is not a very dynamic language, and the C preprocessor doesn't have reflection features.)

Comment: The syntax is not `DEFINE MC_SERVER1="mc1.sdsds.com"` it's `#define MC_SERVER1 "mc1.sdsds.com"`

Answer (score 3):

Defines don't work that way.  They are evaluated at compile time, not execution time, so instances of them are replaced with their values.

Comment: `#define GETCONFIGVALUE(key, sect, var) \
        config_get_value(key, sect, var); \
        if (strlen(var) > 0) \
                TRACE(TRACE_DEBUG, "key "#key" section "#sect" var "#var" value [%s]", var)
`

Comment: This is what I am looking at in the source so it leads me to believe that these are the values from the config file

Comment: @Craig Sparks: `#key` is called stringification (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification). You should avoid it unless you are very sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: That's a nasty macro, won't behave well as an if-then block. This is why lots of macros are wrapped with do {} while (0) as this should be.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to obtain similar effects with macros, through tricks with concatenation (`##`) and stringification (`#`), but it would probably be better for you to just don't use macros.

See [Variable names in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872259/variable-names-in-c) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if they are in an array, but not just with a list of defines as you have.

Such as:

```
const char *servers[] = {
  "server.one",
  "server.two",
};
```

If you're interested in this approach, also see [how to get the length of an array at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array)